# Nginx: Finding the location of specific folder

Tags: nginx, web

Using nginx on my website, am trying to exclude https://www.example.com/folder1 from basic auth. But the problem I don't know `folder1` to which location block it belongs, so then I can exclude it.

Trying to find the folder name in the root directory (like below) doesn't work, since it return so many results with the same name in different directories.

```
find /root_dir/ -iname folder1
```

And excluding just the folder name as location as below doesn't work as well:

```
   location ^~ /folder1/ {
        auth_basic      "off";
        allow all;
    }
```

Any specific way to find https://www.example.com/folder1 to which location block it belong?

Thanks!

Comment: It may be more than one location. Worst case, you may need to repeat all of the main locations within this block. Also, `off` is a keyword and should not be in quotes.

Comment: old nginx versions require the off in quotes, it is not the issue here, am sure of that. But the way to figure out a location block that an application belongs to is my concern here, even if it is related to more than one location block.